# Удаление несуществующего объекта и продление жизни

Tags: c++, указатели

Здравствуйте.

Есть 2 класса: Delived наследник Base. В Base есть точка-указатель на Point, у которого поля int X,Y. Создаю два экземпляра класса Delived и **приравниваю указатели точки Point.** То есть теперь эти экземпляры указывают на 1 объект. Вызываю удаление первого и второго экземпляра, и, понятное дело, у меня падает программа.

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было удалить эти объекты, так, чтобы 2 способа:

1. Программа не упала и проверила, что объекта, который я хочу удалить не существует.
2. Как сделать так, чтобы 1 экземпляр Delived удалился, но содержимое точки не затронул, а когда удаляется другой, точка тоже удалилась.

Еще есть вопрос. Деструктор освобождает память или он нужен, только чтобы удалить поля класса в куче?

```
class Point1
{
public:
    Point1(){};
    Point1(int x, int y){ X = x; Y = y; };
    ~Point1(){};
    int X, Y;
private:

};

class Base
{
public:
    Point1* point;
    Base(){};
    ~Base();

private:

};

Base::~Base(){
    printf_s("~Base");
    if (point)
        delete point;
}
class Delived : public Base
{
public:
    Delived(){}
    ~Delived();

private:

};

Delived::~Delived()
{
    printf_s("~Delived");

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Delived *delived1 = new Delived();
    Delived *delived2 = new Delived();
    delived1->point = new Point1(1, 1);
    delived2->point = delived1->point;

    delete delived1;
    delete delived2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как ответили в [Удалить указатель на объект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/405189#405225), всё уже давно придумано.

Используйте `shared_ptr`

Наследование Base/Derived тут ни при чём.

```
class Base {
public:
    shared_ptr<Point1> point; // превращаем в shared

    // Base(){}; в таком конструкторе нет смысла, хотя бы обнуляли указатель
    // ~Base(); деструктор не нужен - shared_ptr сделает всё сам.
};
```

Теперь в main:

```
// delived1->point = new Point1( 1, 1 ); -- можно и так
delived1->point = make_shared<Point1>(1, 1); // но так лучше
delived2->point = delived1->point;
// удаление Point1 произойдёт автоматически
```

А можно и в main не использовать сырых указателей:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    shared_ptr<Delived> delived1 = make_shared<Delived>();
    shared_ptr<Delived> delived2 = make_shared<Delived>();

    delived1->point = new Point1(1, 1);
    delived2->point = delived1->point;

    // delete delived1; -- тогда явное удаление больше не нужно
    // delete delived2; -- и появляется exception-safety
    return 0;
}
```