# Удалить указатель на объект

Tags: указатели, c++

Всем привет!

Есть такой вопрос.
Допустим, у меня есть несколько указателей на один объект (то есть они клоны).
Мне нужно написать деструктор для такого объекта.
Проблема в том, что я, допустим, хочу удалить только один указатель, т.к. закончил с ним работу, а остальные, да и сам объект, мне нужны.

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как это сделать без утечки памяти?

Просто такую проблему, конечно, можно решить, сначала зануляя очередной указатель. Но если я дойду так до последнего, то сам объект не удалится.
Как я сам думаю, нужно проверить при очередном удалении, есть ли указатели на этот объект, но как это сделать?

Буду признателен, если кто-то ответит.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @the_prog_spb_nub, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Вы не поверите, но это уже давно изобрели и стандартизировали. Называется shared_ptr. Если не сможете нагуглить - дам ссылку.

Comment: всем спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в объект счетчик ссылок (указателей) на него.

"Задействуя" новый указатель -- увеличивайте счетчик.

"Зануляя" очередной указатель -- уменьшайте счетчик.

Когда счетчик обнулится -- удаляйте объект.

Answer (score 0):

> Как я сам думаю, нужно проверить при
> очередном удалении, есть ли указатели
> на этот объект, но как это сделать?

Боюсь, что это возможно только для случая, если вы собираете в коллекцию все ссылки на все инициализированные указатели.

Можно попробовать перегрузить конструктор и деструктор используемого типа данных таким образом, чтобы все инициализируемые объекты сохранялись в некотором статическом списке, а при вызове деструктора, соответственно, удалялись. Там же, в деструкторе, теоретически можно воткнуть проверку на наличие в списке других объектов с такой же ссылкой, и если их нет, то удалять и сам объект, на который указывает ссылка.

Если вышеизложенное по каким-либо причинам "не вариант", то я бы предложил вам копать в сторону алгоритмов работы сборщиков мусора в C# или Java.

Comment: Хм, я, пожалуй, загнул. Вариант, предложенный avp, попроще будет. )